How to interact with the universal router
I am trying to interact with the Universal Router on the Ethereum Mainnet forking network using Hardhat.js.
This is my code.
describe("Swap test", () => {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0xEf1c6E67703c7BD7107eed8303Fbe6EC2554BF6B";
  const USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
  const WETH = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
  const usdc = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", USDC);
  const amountIn = await usdc.balanceOf(deployer.address);
  
  await usdc.approve(UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS, ethers.MaxUint256);


   const universalRouter = await ethers.getContractAt( universalRouterAbi, UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS );
  const commands = "0x08"; // Command for V2_SWAP_EXACT_IN
  const inputs = [ 
       ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode( 
          ["address", "uint256", "uint256", "address[]", "bool"], 
          [ deployer.address, // recipient 
            amountIn, // USDC input 
            1, // min output ETH 
            [usdc.target, weth.target], // path 
            true, // tokens come from msg.sender 
           ] 
         ), 
      ];
      
      await universalRouter.execute(commands, inputs);
})

I have got the error ;
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with an unrecognized custom error (return data: 0xd81b2f2e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
Could you please help me to fix this?
